# Where does GNOME Disks store standby settings?

Tags: gnome, disk-management, disk-utility, standby

I have been trying to figure out where GNOME Disks (gnome-disks) store its standby settings for HDDs (spinning disks). It is the easiest way to configure this, and works perfectly on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04, but since it asks for admin rights when changing the settings, I wonder where it stores its configuration?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Ah, found it! They are in `/etc/udisks2`. Need sudo/admin rights to open the files.